# play! framework 2.2.2 diy build failed on openshift

Tags: java, openshift, playframework-2.2

i have downloaded play 2.2.2 zip file.

and added action_hooks for start/stop.

but the build was failed due to the following info:

```
  play-2.2.2/framework/build: line 23: 320514 Killed
  "$JAVA" ${DEBUG_PARAM} -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M
   -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=192m
   -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
   -XX:MaxPermSize=512M ${JAVA_OPTS} 
   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
   -Dplay.version="${PLAY_VERSION}" 
   -Dplay.home=`dirname $0` 
   -Dsbt.boot.properties=`dirname $0`/sbt/sbt.boot.properties
   -Dsbt.scala.version=${SBT_SCALA_VERSION} 
   ${PLAY_OPTS} -jar `dirname $0`/sbt/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
 remote: -------------------------
 remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
 remote: Activation status: failure
```

how can i make it work?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late, but you would have to set `-Xmx1536M` to a limit your current gear supports (like 512M with standard small gear size).

To accomplish this, you can alter the file `play-2.2.2/framework/build` to adapt this setting.

Otherwise, the supervising openshift process will ungracefully kill your build process as it consumes *a lot* of memory.

**UPDATE:**

I faced the same issues today and ran into the need to solve this properly so I investigated possible solutions a bit further:

1. The play command appends `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to each commands it runs. So setting environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` => -Xmx=512M removes the build failure on smaller gears without having to modify anything
2. Setting `PLAY_OPTS` as well appends a string to each of the commands so I can mix and match different environment variables with an appropriate `openshift.conf` file.

To sum this up and revise my initial answer:

1. set environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to contain a appropriate memory limit Java flag like `-Xmx=512M`, where 512M should match small gear sizes
2. customize any further Play! behaviour with an additional enviroment variable `PLAY_OPTS`

This should work just fine with Play! 2.2.2-I dont know if it does with the upcoming 2.3. But that's another story as the play cartridge would have to be rewritten to only work with sbt.